# IQKeyboardManager with CustomTextField (SkyFloatingLabelTextField) using Swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift3, xcode7, iqkeyboardmanager, skyfloatinglabeltextfield

I am using the `SkyFloatingLabelTextField` which is a custom `UITextField`. After Adding the `IQKeyboardManager` into my Podfile (`pod install`), it was expected that it will automatically handle the keyboard issue.

Any clue to integrate `IQKeyboardManager` with `customTextfield`?

Comment: did you enabled the iqkeyboard manager for that VC ?

Comment: I haven't used the `SkyFloatingLabelTextField` before, but did you enable the `IQKeyboardManager` yet?

Comment: Already enabled the `IQKeyboardManage`r, I am putting `two textfield` in a uiview , iPad Landscape orientation, the `keyboard` is covering the uitextfield on clicking the `first textfield`. is there any way to do for custom uitextfield?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

In AppDelegate :

```
 // Enable IQKeyboardManager for customization
        IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
```

**In UIViewController**

```
class A : UIViewController

viewDidLoad() {
        customizeKeyboard()
    }
    

func customizeKeyboard(){
    
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().shouldShowTextFieldPlaceholder = false
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().toolbarDoneBarButtonItemText = ""
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().shouldHidePreviousNext = true
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().keyboardDistanceFromTextField = 150

    emailTextField.delegate = self
    passwordTextField.delegate = self
    
    // to remove the autocorrect on top of keyboard
    emailTextField.autocorrectionType = .no
    emailTextField.keyboardType = .emailAddress

    // to remove the IQManager view on top of Keyboard
    let emptyUIView = UIView()
    emailTextField.inputAccessoryView = emptyUIView
    passwordTextField.inputAccessoryView = emptyUIView
    forgotEmailTextField.inputAccessoryView = emptyUIView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set keyboard setting in SceneDelegate.swift, Just add this code...

```
 // MARK: - IQKeyboard settings
    func setupIQKeyboard()
    {
        //Enabling keyboard manager
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.keyboardDistanceFromTextField = 15
        
        //Enabling autoToolbar behaviour. If It is set to NO. You have to manually create IQToolbar for keyboard.
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = true
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.toolbarDoneBarButtonItemText = "Done"
        
        //Setting toolbar behavious to IQAutoToolbarBySubviews. Set it to IQAutoToolbarByTag to manage previous/next according to UITextField's tag property in increasing order.
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.toolbarManageBehaviour = .bySubviews
        
        //Resign textField if touched outside of UITextField/UITextView.
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true;
        
        //Show TextField placeholder texts on autoToolbar
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldShowToolbarPlaceholder = true
        
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.previousNextDisplayMode = .alwaysShow
    }
```